# Server stops acknowledging php changes

Tags: php, ajax, webserver, centos

I had a php file that did this:

```
$recresults = array('dupes' => $result, 'total' => $number2);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($recresults);
```

Then I modified the file to this:

```
$recresults = array('dupes' => $result, 'total' => $number2, 'thefield' => "WWW");
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($recresults);
```

But when I checked google dev tools, network tab, I seen that it was not returning the last array element that I added `thefield`. If I attempt to use the variable for that element in my JavaScript I get undefined `data.thefield`.

So to see if changes were being being acknowledged by the server at all I tried changing my code to this:

```
$recresults = array('dupes' => $result, 'total' => $number2, 'thefield' => "WWW");
echo ("WTF SERVER?");
```

I also deleted type `json` on my ajax call. Well after checking I was right about the server not acknowledging my changes to the php file. The return code was still the `json` from the first code set. I tried an old trick of changing the php file's name. Did not work. Tried rebooting server. No dice.

What can I do? The server is not returning any errors.

```
$.post(PROCESSORFILE, {"task": "csv_dedupe", "file_name": file_name, "column_dedupe":                                    elem}, function(data) {
                $("#message").replaceWith('<div id="message" class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><strong>CSV Deduped! </strong><span class="badge badge-important">' + data.thefield + '</span> duplicate<span class="label label-info"> ' + data.dupes+ '</span> found</p></div>')
            });
```

When I return stuff from the php file using json_encode I change the above JS `$.post()` to type `json`.

Comment: Please post the js where you refer to the php file.

Comment: caching maybe? Server-side or client-side ;)

Comment: Yeah tried deleting cache client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, replacing `?` with `&` depending on the content of your `PROCESSORFILE` variable.

```js
var cacheBuster = new Date().getTime() + Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
$.post(PROCESSORFILE + "?t=" + cacheBuster, {"task": "csv_dedupe", "file_name": file_name, "column_dedupe": elem}, function(data) {
    $("#message").replaceWith('<div id="message" class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><strong>CSV Deduped! </strong><span class="badge badge-important">' + data.thefield + '</span> duplicate<span class="label label-info"> ' + data.dupes+ '</span> found</p></div>')
});
```

This is cache-buster code, to ensure a fresh copy of the php page is retrieved.